# Proof that $(v_n)=(1+t)^n$ is a basis for $K[t]$

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis, polynomial-rings

> Prove that $(v_n)=(1+t)^n$ is a Basis for $K[t]$.

I cant figure out how to prove this statement. I need to show linear independence. I tried two things:

The first one is with induction: Let
$$0=\alpha_1 v_1+\ldots+\alpha_n v_n+\alpha_{n+1}v_{n+1}=\alpha_1 v_1+\ldots+(\alpha_n+\alpha_{n+1}+t \alpha_{n+1})v_{n}.$$
Then we find because of the induction hypothesis that $\alpha_n+\alpha_{n+1}+t \alpha_{n+1}=0$.  But we need to conclude that $\alpha_n+1=0$

The second thing I tried is to construct a bijection with the binomial theorem to the standard basis $t^n$. But I only get the map from the basis $(1+t)^n$ to the normal basis $t^n$.

Comment: The (infinite) matrix that changes from the basis $e_n = (1+t)^n$ to $f_n = t^n$ is upper triangular with ones in the diagonal, as $e_n = t^n + \textrm{lower terms}$. This shows that $(e_n)_{n\geqslant 0}$ is a basis. You can even try to fix a finite $N$, look at the finite matrix resulting from changing $(e_n)_{n\leqslant N}$ to $(f_n)_{n\leqslant N}$ and figure out the pattern for the inverse, which is actually very enjoyable to do.

Comment: Another alternative: show by induction that $B_n:=\{(1+t)^k\}_{k=0,\dots,n}$ is a basis for the space $P_n$ of polynomials up to degree $n$. Then show that $B=\bigcup_n B_n$ is a basis of $K[t]=\bigcup_n P_n$.

Comment: L.I. is also pretty easy to show just because each polynomial has a different degree,  so the leading coefficient must be 0, then the next lower, ec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that the map
$$K[t]\ \longrightarrow\ K[t]:\ p(t)\ \longmapsto\ p(1+t),$$
is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

Comment: (+1) This is a nice, simple solution!